# How can i display a value of slider range in 2 place?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I want to display value of `slider range` on the `slider` and other places, I try to use multiple way `getElementById,getElementsByClassName[]`,  `getElementsByName[]` only work on `[0]` or `[1]` but not work on `for loop`.

**This is my code:**

*JavaScript:*

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var output = document.getElementsByName("value_cpu");

for(var i=0; i < output.lenght; i++){
    output[i].innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
        output[i].innerHTML = this.value;
    }
}
```

*HTML:*

```html
<div class="sliderValue">
     <span class="kanade-sl" id="value_cpu" name="value_cpu"> </span>
</div>
<div class="progress" style="height: 25px;">
     <input class="slider ip" id="range" type="range" style="width: 100%;" min="1" max="72" value="1">
     <span class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" ></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known problem with closures on loops: the `slider.oninput` function doesn't "copy" the value of `i` – instead, it keeps a reference to the variable itself. So if `slider.oninput` is called after the loop finished, the `i` value that it will see is `output.length`.

In order to bypass this, you have to copy the value of `i` on a variable outside the function. This variable would have to be declared with `let` rather than `var` (which might not work on ancient versions of Internet Explorer) so a new variable is created for each iteration of the loop:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
    output[i].innerHTML = slider.value;

    let my_i = i;

    slider.oninput = function() {
        output[my_i].innerHTML = this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: i found another way to solve it,  use two different classes, and display the output on those two different containers